# training of robot using Gym to walk

Tags: python, openai-gym

i  am using  this book

[Training of robots using gym](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1788836529)

in this book, there  was example of  `'BipedalWalker-v2'` ,  for this  i used  code from this book

```
import gym
env = gym.make('BipedalWalker-v2')
for i_episode in range(100):
 observation = env.reset()
 for t in range(10000):
     env.render()
     print(observation)
     action = env.action_space.sample()
     observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
     if done:
         print("{} timesteps taken for the episode".format(t+1))
         break
```

but when i run code, it gives me  such errors

```
I:\scientific_python\Scripts\python.exe I:/scientific_python/python_important_functions/Reinforcement_learning_python.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/scientific_python/python_important_functions/Reinforcement_learning_python.py", line 2, in <module>
    env = gym.make('BipedalWalker-v2')
  File "C:\Users\Dato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 156, in make
    return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 101, in make
    env = spec.make(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 72, in make
    cls = load(self.entry_point)
  File "C:\Users\Dato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 18, in load
    fn = getattr(mod, attr_name)
AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'BipedalWalker'
```

so maybe  this attribute is under different  tools right? could you help me in solving  such  a  task?

Answer (score 0):

conda install swig # needed to build Box2D in the pip install

pip install box2d-py # a repackaged version of pybox2d